# Como criar um menu que realize um efeito com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Ndb.png)
[image: Ao clicar na imagem, abre o seguinte perfil]

Gostaria de saber como criar um menu com jquery que ao ser clicado abre uma div como no exemplo acima do Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não uso o jQuery o muito tempo, mas acredito que o que você deseja é um Plugin de Menu Drop Down, veja este link: http://sweet-dropdown.adepto.as/ me parece bem simples de usar, no site tem exemplos de codigos.

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer esse feito de muitas formas.
Uma forma simples de fazer é com JS assim:

```js
            // nav
            $('#navbar-click').click(function() {
                if (!$('.nav').hasClass('open')) {
                    openMenu();
                } else {
                    closeMenu();
                }
            });

            function openMenu(){
                $(function(){
                    // console.log('click');
                    $('.nav').addClass('open').show(300);
                });
            }
            function closeMenu(){
                $(function(){
                    // console.log('click');
                    $('.nav').removeClass('open').hide(300);
                });
            }
```

```css
            .nav{display: none;}
            ul{
                border: 2px solid #bdbdbd;
                background: #cdcdcd;
                border-radius: 2px;
                display: table;
                padding: 15px 15px;
                list-style: none;
            }
            #navbar-click{max-width: 50px;border: 3px solid #a2a2ab;border-radius: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-bar">
            <img id="navbar-click" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="navbar-close"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.